# template extern (vs extern template)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I've ran across a code like this:

```
template<class T> extern void f(T a);
```

in the .h file, and f() is defined with several specific T's in the cpp file.

I couldnt find any explanation about this syntax. I've seen that extern template was introduced in c++11 but they seem to have different syntax...

Can someone elaborate?

Thanks

Comment: @Adriano - I strongly disagree, not the different extern syntax in my question

Comment: It is just the declaration of an extern function template, saying that you're going to define this template in another file (like you do with a normal `extern` function). According to this small article http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html, most compilers throws linker error with this kind of trick.

Comment: @Holt It will only result in a linker error if you try to create an implicit instantiation. The OP mentions the template provides several explicit instantiations (or maybe specialisations) in the `.cpp` file, so as long as you only call those, you're fine.

Comment: @Adriano This is **not** about `extern template`. Notice the position of `extern` with respect to `template`. It's *not* a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Angew you're right, my +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `extern` is superfluous here. It means that functions instantiated from this template have external linkage. It's the normal `extern` you'd apply to an ordinary function definition to indicate it has external linkage. Which is also superfluous, since functions have external linkage by default. So it's the same as

```
template <class T> void f(T a);
```

You've mentioned that several explicit instantiations (or maybe specialisations, your question's not clear on this) are defined in the `.cpp` file. This still has nothing to do with the `extern` keyword being used, and could be done without it as well.

Comment: I was referring to specializations, thanks for the correction. So basically you are saying that extern has no meaning here, and I should get linker errors if I try to use f() in another compilation unit (cpp file)?

Comment: @MarkS I'm saying that `extern` has no meaning here and you should get linker errors if you use (in another translation unit) a specialisation not explicitly defined in the `.cpp` file which has access to the template's definitinon. The rules are always the same: either the translation unit needs access to the template's definition, or an explicit instantiation/specialisation must be defined somewhere the linker can get to it.